# How to use Angular Js ajax with dx-scheduler

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

I am using dx-scheduler calendar and i'm trying to use crud operations for the meetings. I wonder how can i use functions in DevExpress.data.AspNet.createStore instead of their own api methods - here is an example of their API :

```
        DevExpress.data.AspNet.createStore({
            key: "AppointmentId",
            loadUrl: url + "/Get",
            insertUrl: url + "/Post",
            updateUrl: url + "/Put",
            deleteUrl: url + "/Delete",
            onBeforeSend: function(method, ajaxOptions) {
                ajaxOptions.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
            }
        }),
```

I want to achieve this :

```
        DevExpress.data.AspNet.createStore({
            key: "AppointmentId",
            loadUrl: function(){
             $http.get("/getApi").then(function(){
              // manipulate the fetched data
              })
             },
            insertUrl: : function(values){
             // manipulate the values before post
             $http.post("/getApi", values).then(function(){
              
             }),
           
            onBeforeSend: function(method, ajaxOptions) {
                ajaxOptions.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
            }
        }),
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/royBarak80/pen/poEPGYM).

Answer (score 3):

According to Documentation in this [link](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/blob/master/docs/client-side-with-jquery.md#api-reference)

loadUrl - the URL used to load data. I assume that you should pass the URL string here for your get api.
if parameters is needed for your get request you can send them using LoadParams Option

loadParams - additional parameters that should be passed to loadUrl.

and handle the result by  implementing the onLoaded ..
onLoaded - refer to CustomStore.onLoaded.

```
   $scope.schedulerOptions = {
    dataSource: DevExpress.data.AspNet.createStore({
        key: "AppointmentId",
   //    loadUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      loadUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        insertUrl: url + "/Post",
        updateUrl: url + "/Put",
        deleteUrl: url + "/Delete",
        onBeforeSend: function(method, ajaxOptions) {
            ajaxOptions.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
        },
     onLoaded:function(result){
       console.log(result)
       var data = result;
        for (var i in data) {
    data[i].StartDate =  '2020-12-20T10:00:00Z';
    data[i].EndDate =  '2020-12-20T11:00:00Z';
  }
       return data;
      }
    }),
   // remoteFiltering: true,
    dateSerializationFormat: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",
    views: ["day", "workWeek", "month"],
    currentView: "day",
    currentDate: new Date(),
    startDayHour: 9,
    endDayHour: 19,
    height: 600,
    textExpr: "title",
    startDateExpr: "StartDate",
    endDateExpr: "EndDate",
    allDayExpr: "AllDay"
};
```

The result from the get request is printed in the console in the onLoaded function

The data you are using in your example in this json
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Does not contain EndDate , maybe if you modified it to include Start Date and EndDate with the same dateSerializationFormat it will work, I  modified them manually and it worked, I also modified textExpr to display title.

your [Example link](https://codepen.io/wasef89/pen/poErJeZ) modified

In order to use your own Ajax request , you can use the following work around, Initialize the schedulerOptions after you do your Ajax call using the result as data resource.  [Example link](https://codepen.io/wasef89/pen/vYXJOvm)
Html :

```
<div class="dx-viewport demo-container" ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div dx-scheduler="schedulerOptions" ng-if=dataSet></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.dataSet;
  
  var loadFromUrl = function () {
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function(result){
      $scope.dataSet = result.data;
      for (var i in $scope.dataSet) {
        $scope.dataSet[i].startDate =  '2020-12-20T10:00:00Z';
        $scope.dataSet[i].endDate =  '2020-12-20T11:00:00Z';
      }
      
    $scope.schedulerOptions = {
        dataSource: $scope.dataSet,
        dateSerializationFormat: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",
        views: ["day", "workWeek", "month"],
        currentView: "day",
        currentDate: new Date(),
        startDayHour: 9,
        endDayHour: 19,
        height: 600,
        textExpr: "title",
        startDateExpr: "startDate",
        endDateExpr: "endDate",
        allDayExpr: "AllDay"
    };
      
    })
  };

  

  loadFromUrl();
```

Comment: Anabawi - Thanks, i've already tried what you've suggested - the thing is that i need to use my own $http requests because there are some headers that i'm passing that i could not apply in the ajaxOptions - i know that i can add events like onAppointmentAdding and recreate the same behavior - but i thought it will be really nice to do it like in the example.... and just pass functions....

Comment: @RoyBarOn you can do that using the work around mentioned in my updated answer